# How to compare two columns with null values in different tables in Hive

Tags: hive, null, compare

[image]

We have two tables: TableA and TableB. TableA has null values. I want to compare the a.columnA with b.columnA

select count(*)
From tableA a
join tableB b
on a.ID=b.ID
and a.columnA!=B.columnA

The expect result should be 2, but the actual result is zero. This query does not compare the null value. How to compare a column with null value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select count(*) From tableA a join tableB b on a.ID=b.ID and coalesce(a.columnA,'1')!=B.columnA

It works when I use coalesce

Answer (score 2):

Use `<=>` (*null-safe equality operator*) negated comparison which returns `FALSE` in case one of the operands is `null` but `TRUE` when both are `null` and both operands have equal non-null values.

```
select sum(cast(not a.columnA <=> B.columnA) as int) 
From tableA a 
join tableB b on a.ID=b.ID
```

Comment: Hi Vamsi, the <=> is not working, but I find it works with coalesce(a.columnA,'1')!=B.columnA

Comment: @Anson .. check out the edit..using `coalesce` for such comparison isn't suggested because table B might have `null`s in the future and the column values might have default values used in `coalesce`..